# My Redux persisted store is not persisting the state properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, persist

I am creating a web app using Django as backend and React on frontend. Am pretty far ahead and almost ready to deploy on my staging server, currently just clearing some issues before I do that and I found out that my redux store which am using your persisting the state doesnt function properly. Everything works fine in terms of authentication, and navigating between pages, but when I hit refresh once the state is still there and when I hit the refresh again the user gets logged out.

I am new to Redux so I am not sure what could be the problem, I followed couple of tutorials and I tried to keep the configuration as simple as I can in order to avoid the unescessery complications.

I am using axiosInstance as interceptor to re authenticate user on every api call so I figured maybe thats where the issue lies but am not sure since its working good with the rest of the functions when it comes to login, logout, register, permissions etc..

Here is my redux store configuration:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "./api/apiSlice";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import authReducer from "../features/auth/authSlice";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import formReducer from "../features/modal/formReducer";
import modalReducer from "../features/modal/modalReducer";
import elementReducer from "../features/elements/elementReducer";
import editPageReducer from "../features/elements/editPageReducer";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer),
  formState: formReducer,
  modalState: modalReducer,
  elementState: elementReducer,
  editPageState: editPageReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [thunk, apiSlice.middleware],
  devTools: true,
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

And here is my axios Interceptor:

```
import axios from "axios";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectCurrentToken,
  setCredentials,
  logOut,
} from "../features/auth/authSlice";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import store from "../app/store";

const useAxiosInstance = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const token = useSelector(selectCurrentToken);
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);

  const createAxiosInstance = (token) => {
    const instance = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
    });

    // Set the authorization header
    if (token) {
      instance.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return instance;
  };

  const axiosInstanceRef = useRef(createAxiosInstance(token));

  axiosInstanceRef.current.defaults.headers.common[
    "Authorization"
  ] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  
  axiosInstanceRef.current.interceptors.request.use(async (req) => {
    if (!token) {
      dispatch(logOut(user, token));
      console.log("IS IT LOGGGED OUT!!!!!")
      localStorage.removeItem("tokens");
      // Handle the case where the token is not available
      // e.g., redirect the user to the login page
      // or perform other necessary actions
    }

    const isExpired = dayjs.unix(jwt_decode(token).exp).diff(dayjs()) < 1;
    const getRefreshToken = localStorage.getItem("tokens");

    if (!isExpired) return req;

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/refresh/`,
        {
          refresh: getRefreshToken,
        }
      );
      localStorage.setItem("tokens", response.data.refresh);

      const newToken = response.data.access;

      // Update the axios instance with the new token
      axiosInstanceRef.current = createAxiosInstance(newToken);
      axiosInstanceRef.current.defaults.headers.common[
        "Authorization"
      ] = `Bearer ${newToken}`;

      req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newToken}`;
      dispatch(setCredentials({ ...response.data, user }));

      return req;
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle refresh token request error
      localStorage.removeItem("tokens");
      dispatch(logOut()); // Replace with your logout logic
      throw error;
    }
  });

  return axiosInstanceRef.current;
};

export default useAxiosInstance;
```

I believe issue lies somewhere here but I am not sure where exactly.

Any help or feedback is very appreciated!

Comment: I can't debug your code by stepping though it since I can't run it, but the one odd thing that sticks out to me is the `axiosIntanceRef` creation with `const axiosInstanceRef = useRef(createAxiosInstance(token));`. Here `createAxiosInstance` is called each time the `useAxiosInstance` hook runs. `createAxiosInstance` creates a new instance each time. Since the base instance doesn't ever change, and because the default headers are set each time outside `createAxiosInstance`, I don't think `createAxiosInstance` is necessary at all. Move `instance` outside the hook so it's a stable reference.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any interceptor callback cleanup functions to remove them, so maybe there are "stale" callbacks that don't have the token closed over in scope and log the user out when they run, or there is some unexpected exception/rejection happening and this is taking the sad path in the interceptor handler. I think you really just need to set some breakpoints and  step through the code to see what is happening versus what you are expecting.

Comment: What do you mean by moving instance outside the hook?

Comment: Outside the `useAxiosInstance` function scope.

Comment: Ok my issue is resolved now..the problem was in my store, the way how I wrapped my auth reducer with persistConfig. So instead of this:  auth: persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer), I had to change it to this:  auth:  authReducer, and now it works.